# How to map nested child object properties in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have current map:

```
CreateMap<Article, ArticleModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BaseContentItem, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BaseContentItem))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BaseContentItem.TopicTag, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BaseContentItem.TopicTag))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MainImage, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.MainImage))
    .ReverseMap();
```

The error I get is:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression 'dest =>
>   dest.BaseContentItem.TopicTag' must resolve to top-level member and
>   not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child
>   type or the AfterMap option instead.'

How can I map this?

Comment: You need ForPath instead of ForMember.

Answer (score 83):

This should work. Use `ForPath` instead of `ForMember`

```
CreateMap<Article, ArticleModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BaseContentItem, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BaseContentItem))
    .ForPath(dest => dest.BaseContentItem.TopicTag, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BaseContentItem.TopicTag))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MainImage, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.MainImage))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: what if dest.BaseContentItem.TopicTag is a list ? How can we handle this

Comment: What is the equivalent of `opt.ConvertUsing` on a `ForPath` if I want a custom IValueConverter for the nested mapping?  This seems to only be available for ForMember.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried forPath but I am also facing the same issue

On the client I get a 404.

```
namespace EternityEduca.Helpers
{
    public class MappingProfiles : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<CourseCategory, CourseCategoryToReturnDto>()
                .ForMember(c => c.CourseObj, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CourseObj))
                .ForMember(c => c.CategoryTypeObj, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CategoryTypeObj))
                .ForPath(d => d.CourseObj.Img_Url, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CourseObj.Img_Url))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class CourseCategoryToReturnDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Course CourseObj { get; set; }
        public CategoryType CategoryTypeObj { get; set; }
    }
```

Client:

```
getCourseCategories(typeId?: number) {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (typeId) {
      params = params.append('typeId', typeId.toString());
    }
    //Pipe is a wrapper around any other state X operator that can be used in Rxjs
    return this.http.get<IPaginationCourseCategory>(this.baseUrl + 'courses/coursecategories', { observe: 'response', params })
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          //response body will be Pagination
          return response.body;
        })
      );
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{courseCategory.courseObj.img_Url}}" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;" data-holder-rendered="true">
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like an answer.